# Parameterized SQL select statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, select

I am writing a program that pulls data from a SQL table connected to an Access database and then populates a `DataGridView` on a Windows form.

I am wondering if there is a way in the select statement to set parameters around the data I am pulling such as, if I select a column and the data is 1 or 0, the `DataGridView` can display 1 as yes and 0 as no.

I have tried adjusting the select statement and writing cell formatting functions but nothing seems to be working.

For example:

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select IA, CASE 1 return 'Yes' case else return 'NO' FROM dbo_tblPLOps_Data WHERE LANID= '" & txtRepID.Text & "' and date >= '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' and date <= '" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "'",    newScoreConn)
```

I tried this too:

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select IA IF (IA = 1, 'yes', 'no')FROM dbo_tblPLOps_Data WHERE LANID= '" & txtRepID.Text & "' and date >= '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' and date <= '" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "'",    newScoreConn)
```

I am able to adjust the pull and change the `DataGridView` column header:

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select IA as [Info Accuracy] FROM dbo_tblPLOps_Data WHERE LANID= '" & txtRepID.Text & "' and date >= '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' and date <= '" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "'",    newScoreConn)
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283894/how-to-output-a-boolean-from-a-query

Comment: You aren't using parameters.  You should.  It would prevent sql injection and formatting errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to adjust the syntax of the select statement and get what I was looking for:

```
IIF(IA = 5, 'yes','no')
```

I knew it had to be some variation of an Access `IF`  statement but was having a hard time getting the syntax to display correctly.